# What is the word for an image hidden inside a painting?

Tags: single-word-requests

My father-in-law has a painting by Vu Cao Dam of two girls and a man on horseback.  He found a hidden fox in the painting, and today we were looking at it and found some more.

What do you call it when an artist intentionally puts a hidden image within a larger work of art?  My father-in-law swears there is a word, and that it is a general term which can apply to different media.  It can apply to actors who make cameos or easter eggs in software.

What word is this?

Comment: A bit off-topic, but this reminds me of [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), which refers to the hiding of messages, often in clever ways. It has had something of a resurgence in the digital age.

Comment: Ever read "The Mezzotint"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per snubian I suggest *steganograph*.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use that word only for textual information or, as a recent extension to the meaning, digital information encoded in the actual bits of a computer encoding of the image.

Comment: How do you pronounce it? steh-NAG-oh-graph? STEG-uh-nuh-graph? Something else?

Comment: Definitely not Steh NAG, since it's spelled "stegan". I go with your second choice.

Answer (score 5):

The term [anamorphosis](http://www.planetperplex.com/en/subcategory/hidden-images/anamorphosis/l/) seems to be close – it describes a type of concealed image that requires viewing either through/with a special device, or from a particular perspective, in order to reveal a feature or shape that is not immediately apparent to the casual observer.

I have also discovered that 2D optical illusions bearing hidden 3D projections that your brain can be tricked into seeing, (Magic Eye-type images), are called [autostereograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autostereogram).

Answer (score 2):

I would call it a hidden, double, multiple, or ambiguous image; or, if the hidden image were especially non-sequitorial, perhaps "a shining example of the [paranoiac-critical method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranoiac-critical_method)".  Some hidden images are due to the [Figure-Ground phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure-ground_%28perception%29), others are due to [Gestalt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology), others I'm sure are due to other things.  Other than "easter egg", though, I can't really think of another alternative.  Perhaps the links will have something I missed.

P.s.  Dali's [*The Endless Enigma*](http://www.friendsofart.net/en/art/salvador-dali/the-endless-enigma-1) is the best example of multiple hidden or ambiguous images that I know of.

Comment: You should check out Pavel Tchelitchew's [Hide and Seek](http://petulantrumblings.com/wp-content/gallery/art-pause/hideandseek1940-42.jpg).

Answer (score -2):

Visual penetration, which allows a special point of focus.

Comment: Visual penetration! That's an interesting word. Do you have any references? Inspiration for this answer?